# How do I get the SSH executable that git is using

Tags: git

Is there any easy way to determine what SSH git will use when I do a `git clone`? I was trying to debug an issue with git bash on Windows using some missing ssh path because of a GIT_SSH env variable I didn't realize was being set and I could have really used a `which git-ssh` type of command.